# Getting error while loading ebpf program into kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf

Why I am getting this error when I want to load the ebpf program into kernel??

**ebpf_prog.c:**

```
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct bpf_object *obj;
    int map_fd, prog_fd;
    int i, sock;
    FILE *f;
    
if (bpf_prog_load("ebpf_prog.o", BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, &obj, &prog_fd)){
        printf("The kernel didn't load the BPF program\n");
        return -1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

**load_prog.c:**

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct bpf_object *obj;
    int map_fd, prog_fd;
    int i, sock;
    FILE *f;


    if (bpf_prog_load("ebpf_prog.o", BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, &obj, &prog_fd)){
        printf("The kernel didn't load the BPF program\n");
        return -1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
$ gcc ebpf_prog.c -c -o ebpf_prog.o
$ gcc load_prog.c -o load_prog -lbpf
$ ./load_prog
libbpf: elf: sock_example.o is not a valid eBPF object file
The kernel didn't load the BPF program
```

what's wrong with my code??

Answer (score 2):

Your `load_prog.c` refers to `sock_example.o` as the object file containing the BPF program, but that object file is actually called `ebpf_prog.o`.

Comment: Hi pchaingo. No that's OK. it is because of typo mistake in my question and the Orginal file is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ebpf_prog.c` isn’t a valid eBPF program, but that might just be a copy-paste error since it’s nearly the same as your `load_prog.c`. (I’m assuming the `ebpf_prog.o`/`sock_example.o` mismatch is also a copy-paste error.)

The main error is that you’re building it as an ELF binary; eBPF programs need to be built as eBPF byte code:

```
clang -target bpf ...
```

Since you’re using libbpf, see [the libbpf bootstrap tutorial](https://nakryiko.com/posts/libbpf-bootstrap/).